# PHP Problem uploading files with drag and drop

Tags: php, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I am uploading a file using HTML5 Drag n Drop Feature. Where it shows the % of file uploaded.

On My Test Env. I can literally see the file getting copied over the server. For e.g if i upload 200M File, i can see temp file being created and gradually getting bigger in size.

But on Prod ENV. it just copies the whole file.

Am i missing anything in server apache or php configuration. Following is the sample code which am using to write the file gradually.

```
    $input = fopen("php://input", "r");
    //$temp = tmpfile();
    $target = fopen($path, "w");
    $realSize = stream_copy_to_stream($input, $target);
    fclose($input);
    fclose($target);
    if ($realSize != $this->getSize()){
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP , in itself does not support gradual uploads. You need http://pecl.php.net/package/uploadprogress or APC like http://www.haughin.com/2007/10/23/php-upload-progress-with-php-52-apc/ this article says.